# I want to convert .py to .exe using pyinstaller, but every time I try, it says "TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)"

Tags: python, integer, pyinstaller

I've tried updating and everything, just can't get the file to convert because of that one error

Here is the code

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/hogurocutu.py

Comment: Please include the .spec file.

Comment: Which Python version are you using

Comment: Try updating ```pyinstaller```